# Android: Vector Triangle with background Image

Tags: android, xml, vector, shapes

Im trying to set an Image within the boundaries of a triangle - set as Vector.

With ease I created a VectorTriangle but now im looking for a solution to cut an Image to the same size and mould it.

First approach i did was to get the "shape-coords" (pathdata) of the triangle. With these i thought i "cut" the image and place it behind the vector. This seems to be a dead end. Theres no way to mould the image with help of pathdata.

I know some techniques with shapes (Circles, Rects(Bitmaps)) but none of them are helpful for vectors.

Is there any idea to realize that?
Something i didnt see yet?

[Example Image (Center Triangle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2TxD.jpg)

Comment: read about porter duff xfer modes or see `BitmapShader` docs

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaats Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can add image in the background and put that triangle as the src of the imageview. Point to be noted is that the triangle should be transparent in the center as a result it would make the background visible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this today.
An Image in the Backround of... Activity?
This proccess must be done over several times... Like an Object. Your solution may cost a lot of resources and i think that i cant use it as like an object either an activity